# Unable to send mail from digital ocean server using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, nodemailer

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
      user: process.env.USER, // generated ethereal user this is in .env
      pass: process.env.PASS // generated ethereal password this is in .env
  },
  tls:{
    rejectUnauthorized:false
  }
});
```

This is my transporter code it works fine in my windows machine but when i run it from digital ocean server Iam getting this error

```
0|app  | Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
0|app  | 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 12sm2897109pfb.3 - gsmtp
0|app  |     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
0|app  |     at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1523:34)
0|app  |     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:550:26)
0|app  |     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
0|app  |     at SMTPConnection._onData (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/root/apps/Prathik/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
0|app  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
0|app  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
0|app  |     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
0|app  |   code: 'EAUTH',
0|app  |   response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
0|app  |     '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 12sm2897109pfb.3 - gsmtp',
0|app  |   responseCode: 535,
0|app  |   command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
0|app  | }
```

Please help

Comment: It seems likely your gmail username and password are not set up correctly as environment variables on your server. Try `echo $USER` and see what you get.

Comment: Its setup perfectly its working in windows and ubuntu in my laptop

Comment: I was able to send emails using smtp while I had my password saved as env variable:
EMAIL_PASSWORD="password"
but it didn't work on digitalocean server
I had to remove quote and leave it as
EMAIL_PASSWORD=password

maybe it will help someone